# Why do game developers put many images into one big image?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, image, ipad

Over the years I've often asked myself why game developers place many small images into a big one. But not only game developers do that. I also remember the good old Winamp MP3 player had a user interface design file which was just one huge image containing lots of small ones.

I have also seen some big javascript GUI libraries like ext.js using this technique. In ext.js there is a big image containing many small ones.

One thing I noticed is this: No matter how small my PNG image is, the Finder on the Mac always tells me it consumes at least 4kb. Which is heck of a lot if you have just 10 pixels.

So is this done because storing 20 or more small images into a big one is much more memory efficient versus having 20 separate files, each of them probably with it's own header and metadata?

Is it because locating files on the file system is expensive and slow, and therefore much faster to simply locate only one big image and then split it up into smaller ones, once it is loaded into memory?

Or is it lazyness, because it is tedious to think of so many file names?

Is ther a name for this technique? And how are those small images separated from the big one at runtime?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/2d-graphics-why-use-spritesheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of these answers are right.  The reason we pack multiple images into one big "sprite sheet" or "texture atlas" is to avoid swapping textures during rendering.

OpenGL and Direct-X take a performance hit when you draw from one image (texture) and the switch to another, so we pack multiple images into one big image and then we can draw several (or hundreds) of images and never switch textures.  It has nothing to do with the 4K file size (or hasn't in 15 years).

Also, up until very recently, textures had to by powers of 2 (64, 128, 256) and if your game had lots of odd sized images, that's a lot of wasted memory.  Packing them in a single texture could save a lot of space.

Comment: Does that also apply outside of OpenGL? For example on the web (as done in ext.js, a JavaScript GUI lib)?

Comment: I hope you see this but, what about swapping textures when you have to redraw a texture? you even have to unbind it to modify it right?

Comment: in web applications also there's a performance hit (request) when swapping src. Not about the switch to but the load time. when you have a sprite you know the whole image is there so a hover will be instantaneous too.

Answer (score 5):

This is called [*spriting*](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) - and there are various reasons to do it in different situations.

For web development, it means that only *one* web request is required to fetch the image, which can be a lot more efficient than several separate requests. That's more efficient in terms of having less overhead due to the individual requests, and the final image file may well be smaller in total than it would have been otherwise.

The same sort of effect *may* be visible in other scenarios - for example, it may be more efficient to store and load a single large image file than multiple small ones, depending on the file system. That's entirely *aside* from any efficiencies gained in terms of the raw "total file size", and is due to the per file overhead (a directory entry, block size etc). It's a bit like the "per request" overhead in the web scenario, but due to slightly different factors.

Answer (score 2):

The 4kb usage is a side effect of how files are stored on disk. The smallest possible addressable bit of storage in a filesystem is a block, which is usually a fixed size of 512, 1024, 2048, etc... bytes. In your Mac's case, it's using 4k blocks. That means that even a 1-byte file will require at least 4kbytes worth of physical space to store, as it's not possible for the file system to address any storage unit SMALLER than 4k.

The reasons for these "large" blocks vary, but the big one is that the more "granular" your addressing gets (the small the blocks), the more space you waste on indexes to list which blocks are assigned to which files. If you had 1-byte sized blocks, then for every byte of data you store in a file, you'd also need to store 1+ bytes worth of usage information in the file system's metadata, and you'd end up wasting at least HALF of your storage on nothing but indexes.

The converse is true - the bigger the blocks, the more space is wasted for every smaller-than-one-block sized file you store, so in the end it comes down to what tradeoff you're willing to live with.

Comment: Great explanation! So I assume on the iPhone even a 1 pixel PNG is going to waste 4kb and therefore it is good to pack many such small images into a bigger one. Does this also mean that when such a small file is loaded, the OS will allocate 4 kb of memory to open the file?

Comment: The os will allocate a 4kb buffer somewhere to read the file, as the deep-down filesystem operations are all block-based as well. But once the actual file data trickles up to the level your code works in, only 1byte of memory would actually be used.

Comment: this is a low level disk formatting issue - it's not clear that the iOS device = Mac OS device = 4k byte blocks, they may be smaller since the storage is smaller.  As Marc says, this does NOT cause the memory used to be larger!  (And it's likely that a 4kb buffer is not needed either, but that's worst case.  I would say the os *may* allocate a 4kb buffer)

Answer (score 1):

The reasons are a bit different in different environments.

On the web the main reason is to reduce the number of requests to the web server. Each requests creates overhead, most notably a separate round trip over the network.

When fetching from good ol' mechanical hard drives good read performance requires contiguous data. If you save data in lots of files you get extra seek-time for each file. There is also the block size to consider. Files are made out of blocks, in your case 4kB. When reading a file of one byte you need to read a whole block anyway. If you have many small images you can stuff a whole bunch of them in a single disk block and get them all in the same time as if you had only one small image in the block.

Comment: Makes sense! How are these images separated into smaller ones at runtime? I assume copying regions out of that big "map" is not so efficient right?

Comment: Copying data in memory is several orders of magnitude faster than reading the same data from disk or over the the network. There are usually build in method for drawing parts of images on certain locations on the screen. They are usually very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason from days of yore was palletes.

If you did one image you could theme it with one pallete Colour = 14 = light grey with a hint of green.

If you did lots of little images you had to make sure you used the same pallet for every one while designing them, or you got all sort of artifacts.

Given you had one pallete then you could manipulate that, so everything currently green could be made red, by flipping one value in the palletes instead of trawling through every image.

Lots of simple animations like fire, smoke, running water are still done with this method.